# Send 5k plus objects by string delim to SQL PROC param, then split, parse and loop for each object in Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have a quoting system where we are cleaning the data read in from a imported file, and in the for each of the read line in the file, we hit SQL to see if the item exist, or if it is a typo / not found / etc to get the fuzzy found results back for each on. That way afterwards, and the end user can then correct the bad / not found items, to the correct ones we found in the fuzzy search.

That being said, this scrub tool is used by importing a CSV file that could be anywhere from 500 records to 10k records.

When i do it per line, im hitting SQL many many times quickly causing a lack in efficiency and speed.

I was hoping to try the following to handle one call to SQL, and do it all on the  SQL server to test difference in speeds.

This is currently a small snippet to get to the point of this question, of how it looks up if the item is existing currently in our pricing central DB, or if we need to run a fuzzy search and return a few items for the end user to select correct price.

This is how i reading the file since its large, and is blazing fast:

```
 using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(uploadedFile.InputStream))
 {
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
      {
            // store in array here... for later looping to the SQL lookups
      }
 }

 // After I read the entire file, then placed into array of rows,
 // the next is how i loop to lookup each match, por find best matches using fuzzy
 foreach (var baseQuoteItem in quoteDataRows)
 {
     hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendMessage(connectionId, String.Format("Reading record {0} of {1} ", callCounter.ToString(), fullRecords.ToString()));

     // service away
     var searches = _quoteEntityService.GetAssetsFromFuzzySearch(baseQuoteItem.Manufacturer, baseQuoteItem.Model, baseQuoteItem.Description).ToList();

     int totalFoundResults = searches.Count();

     baseQuoteItem.SuggestionsList = new List<QuoteEntityItemVM>();
}
```

What I would like to try is build all the objects, then send it with delimiter of properties by a comma, then each object by a ^. That way the stored procedure parameter would have data like below:

```
obj.P1, obj.P2, obj.P3 ^ obj2.P!1, obj2.P2, obj2.P3 ^
```

and so on. Then I could send thousands of objects with the properties I need in the query in as a string, and loop through each entity between ^ and then do the lookup on them using the values of that entity by splitting the properties by comma.

Example in SQL (I know syntax here is wrong it is for demonstration purposes only":

```
@OBJECTS = split(@ITEMS on ","); //now i have rows or array of all items.
```

then

```
foreach(var i in @OBJECTS)
BEGIN
    do fuzzy search here for i
END
```

Is this possible and how would I set this up?

Here is the current SQL Server stored procedure I am using:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DATA_FuzzyAssetMacth] 
    @Mfr AS VARCHAR(100),
    @Model AS VARCHAR(100),
    @Desc AS VARCHAR(150)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @_MFRFIND INT;
    DECLARE @_MDNUMBER INT;
    DECLARE @MDDESC VARCHAR(150);

    DECLARE @_SEARCH VARCHAR(150);

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPPMFR') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE #TEMP

    IF OBJECT_ID('tmpdb..#TEMPPMFRMODEL') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE #TEMPPMFRMODEL

    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP 
        WHERE POP.Manufacturer = @Mfr 
          AND POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model) > 0)
    BEGIN
        --DIG DONE AND RETURN
        SELECT 
            POP.Manufacturer, POP.ManufacturerPartNumber, 
            POP.Description AS ManufacturerDescription, 
            CONVERT(money, POP.Price) AS Price, POP.ItemType, 
            CAST('1' AS BIT) AS MfrFound, CAST('1' AS BIT) AS ModelFound, 
            CAST('-1' AS int) AS Score 
        FROM 
            Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP
        WHERE 
            POP.Manufacturer = @Mfr 
            AND POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model
    END
    ELSE
        -- CHECK IF WE HAVE MATCH AT MFR LEVEL, THEN MODEL, THEN DESCRIPTION
        -- IF WE DO NOT HAVE IT AT ONE LEVEL, APPLY SELECT TO BASE LEVELS, THEN FUZZY SEARCH NEXT LEVEL
        IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP 
            WHERE POP.Manufacturer = @Mfr) > 0)
        BEGIN
            IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP 
                WHERE POP.Manufacturer = @Mfr 
                  AND POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model) > 0)
                --DIG DONE AND RETURN
                SELECT 
                    POP.Manufacturer, POP.ManufacturerPartNumber, 
                    POP.Description AS ManufacturerDescription, 
                    CONVERT(money, POP.Price) AS Price, POP.ItemType, 
                    CAST('1' AS BIT) AS MfrFound, CAST('1' AS BIT) AS ModelFound,
                    CAST('-1' AS int) AS Score 
                FROM 
                    Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP
                WHERE  
                    POP.Manufacturer = @Mfr 
                    AND POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model
            ELSE
            -- WE NEED TO USE FUZZY ON MODEL NUMBER
            BEGIN
                SELECT 
                    PMFR.Manufacturer, PMFR.ManufacturerPartNumber, 
                    PMFR.Description AS ManufacturerDescription, 
                    CONVERT(money, PMFR.Price) AS Price, 
                    PMFR.ItemType, CAST('1' AS BIT) AS MfrFound, 
                    CAST('0' AS BIT) AS ModelFound
                INTO 
                    #TEMPPMFR
                FROM 
                    Products_OurProducts_Products AS PMFR
                WHERE 
                    PMFR.Manufacturer = @Mfr;

                SELECT TOP 5 
                    P.Manufacturer, P.ManufacturerPartNumber, 
                    P.ManufacturerDescription, P.Price, P.ItemType, 
                    P.MfrFound, P.ModelFound, fms.score AS Score
                FROM 
                    #TEMPPMFR AS P
                CROSS APPLY 
                    (SELECT
                         dbo.FuzzyControlMatch(@Model, P.ManufacturerPartNumber) AS score) AS fms
                ORDER BY 
                    fms.score DESC
            END
        END
        ELSE
            -- IF HAVE A FUZZY AT MFR, THEN WE NEED TO GRAB BEST CHOICE AND GO DOWN. 
            -- WE COULD HAVE POSSIBLY CANDIDATES FOR THIS SO WHEN TO STOP RECURSIVENESS AND SAY ADDING NEW ENTRY?   
        BEGIN
            --AT MOMENT JUST RETURN TOP FOUND MFR THEN SELECT FROM THAT TO SEE RESULT TESTS
            DECLARE @TEMP_MFRNAME VARCHAR(100);

            --FIRST LETS SEE IF SENT MODEL EXIST AND IF SO, PULL THAT THEN RANK AGAINST MFR FOR IT
            IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products_OurProducts_Products AS POP WHERE POP.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model) > 0)
                BEGIN
                    --DIG DONE AND RETURN
                    SELECT PMFR.Manufacturer, PMFR.ManufacturerPartNumber, PMFR.Description AS ManufacturerDescription, CONVERT(money,PMFR.Price) AS Price, PMFR.ItemType, CAST('0' AS BIT) AS MfrFound, CAST('1' AS BIT) AS ModelFound 
                    INTO #TEMPPMFRMODEL
                    FROM Products_OurProducts_Products AS PMFR
                    WHERE PMFR.ManufacturerPartNumber = @Model;

                    SELECT top 5 P.Manufacturer, P.ManufacturerPartNumber,P.ManufacturerDescription, P.Price, P.ItemType, P.MfrFound, P.ModelFound, fms.score  as Score
                    FROM #TEMPPMFRMODEL AS P
                    CROSS APPLY (select dbo.FuzzyControlMatch(@Mfr, P.Manufacturer) AS score) AS fms
                    ORDER by fms.score desc
                END
            --THEN SEE IF EXIST USING FUZZY FOUND MFR, TO SEEK MODEL NUMBER ETC.
        END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPPMFR') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #TEMP

    IF OBJECT_ID('tmpdb..#TEMPPMFRMODEL') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #TEMPPMFRMODEL
END
```

Comment: Why not use a UDTT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) to send the data structured - will save you a massive parsing headache.

Comment: Definitely agree with @DaleBurrell...you can send a whole table to a stored procedure. It's much easier and performs better.

Comment: I do not even know about those. Doe sit work hand in hand with Entity framework etc? I will read on it and thanks for the info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971331/how-to-use-the-procedure-with-user-defined-table-type-in-entity-framework

Comment: If you are importing large files, consider `SqlBulkCopy` into a staging table. Incredibly fast, and can then pass the table into the stored proc if needed.

Comment: You do not need to count rows to determine if something exists. Counting can be quite slower if you are not careful. E.g., replace that 3rd IF statement with "if exists(select * from Products_OurProducts_Products as POP ..."). And for the love of future generations, really **REALLY** reconsider your naming standards.

Comment: Reading in large files is blazing fast with how i handle it. It is after that when i need to loop through each CSV row, and send that item to be looked up in SQL to see if we have it, then pull the price for it, or if not due to typo, or being a new record now in our central pricing system and handle the fuzzy matching.

Comment: So basically, the question should be, how to send a list if 6k-10-k objects to SQL and handle them being looked up. Should i do one hit per item in the loop ( i think not) or send the entire list to SQL at one time, then parse and loop within SQL in one run through. Kind og like send a list of json item, parse them handle the SQL, and return the new list of JSON back to the C# data layer to handle the return.

Comment: So basically, i want to test if done all in SQL or in code behind with many hits to SQL is faster. I also have to consider minimally locking the tables. Sorry for long comment. -Thanks-

Comment: liking @Dale Burrell's method so far. Seems good and will try. Though for each item that goes in, one entry would be returned if the item is found, and if ot found, i need a column that is like a sub-list returned that i could parse. If the item does not exist, it will then run the fuzzy search to find all possible matches that are seemingly close, i would return that in a single column using delimiter, and then parse in the data layer when im assigning the entity complex type returned.  If this works good i will post he full final result that worked in here, and then may help future users.