# EF Core execute procedure with many User-Defined Table Type

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

Hi i have a problem with execute stored procedure in EF Core.
Procedure have 3 parameters:
[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpGa9.png)

The User-Defined Table Type look lik this:
[User-Defined Table Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7P07.png)

When i try execute procedure i always have a error:

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'SqlParameter[]'.

C# code:

```
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>(); ;
        parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@id_zmiennej", 138)
            {
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            }
        );
        using (var dt = new DataTable())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("wartosc", typeof(int));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 2010;
            dr["wartosc"] = 2010;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 2011;
            dr["wartosc"] = 2011;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@lata", dt)
            {
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                TypeName = "[dbo].[TabIntType]"
            };
            parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
        using (var dt = new DataTable())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("wartosc", typeof(int));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 10;
            dr["wartosc"] = 10;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 11;
            dr["wartosc"] = 11;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@okresy", dt)
            {
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                TypeName = "[dbo].[TabIntType]"
            };
            parameters.Add(parameter);           
        }
        var data = _context.Data.FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetData {0}", parameters).ToList();
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: You appear to be mixing EntityFramework and non-EF methods.   Whilst you can call SPROCs in EF, you appear to just be using EF to provide a connection string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the Procedure with User Defined Table Type in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971331/how-to-use-the-procedure-with-user-defined-table-type-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Issues I can see: You need `FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetData {0}", parameters.ToArray<object>())`. Don't dispose the `DataTable` it's unnecessary and will cause it to get nulled out before execution of the command. You also need to set `parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface , i just add `Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;` and i change `_context.Data.FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetData {0}", parameters).ToList();` to `_context.Data.FromSqlRaw("dbo.GetData {0},{1},{2}", parameters.ToArray()).ToList();` and it's start working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameters as a `List<SqlParameter>`, whereas `FromSqlRaw` expects a `SqlParameter[]` array (or variable length `params`). So you need to convert it to an array.

Also, you have three parameters and are only passing one, and ideally you should pass by name

```cs
FromSqlRaw(@"
EXEC dbo.GetData
  @id_zmiennej = {0},
  @lata = {1},
  @okresy = {2};
", parameters.ToArray<object>())
```